# Dynamic $_SESSION variable session names for loop PHP

Tags: php, session, for-loop

I'm creating dynamic `$_SESSION` variables with a simple for loop to print dates.

```
if($dateweekday ==='Tuesday'){
for ($v=1;$v<=4;$v++){
$ttt = 'tuesday_'.$v;
}
echo $_SESSION[$ttt] = $newdateformat ;
echo "<br>";
}
```

result

```
2017-9-19 
2017-9-26 
2017-10-03 
2017-10-10
```

Looks good. But then my concern is the value of `$_SESSION[$ttt]`. The result should be

```
$_SESSION['tuesday_1'] = 2017-9-19;
$_SESSION['tuesday_2'] = 2017-9-26;
$_SESSION['tuesday_3'] = 2017-10-03;
$_SESSION['tuesday_4'] = 2017-10-10;
```

When I `var_dump($_SESSION[$ttt])` this is what I get

```
string(10)
string(9)
string(9)
string(9)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: There is something odd about the code, notice that you create key inside loop but you echo session variable only once outside loop after the loop is done. Shouldn't the echo be inside the loop with `$ttt = 'tuesday_'.$v;`? Also you echoing `$newdateformat` as `$_SESSION[$ttt]` is already of its value (I'm 90% sure about it).

Comment: @Mr_KoKa:
 
I know but when I do this `for($v=1;$v<=4;$v++){
    $ttt = 'tuesday_'.$v;
    echo $_SESSION[$ttt] = $newdateformat;
}`
the forloop loop 4 times over each date which is not the desired effect.

Comment: Ok, so you can just replace your loop with `$ttt = 'tuesday_4';` (Or the code is not complete). You still need to take a look at the first thing I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two things:

**1.**
Lets say we have `$t` set to `'value_before'`:

```
$t = 'value_before';
```

Now:

```
echo $t = 'value_after';
```

The above code is equal to:

```
$t = 'value_after';
echo $t;
```

So the result is echoing 'value_after', and you never echo the old value ('value_before').

**2.** The other thing I noticed is that you prepare your variable many times in a loop, and then you echoing it only once, this part of your code:

```
for ($v=1;$v<=4;$v++){
    $ttt = 'tuesday_'.$v;
}

echo $_SESSION[$ttt] = $newdateformat;
```

So only thing you echo is `'$_SESSION['tuesday_4'] = $newdateformat'` and ano of `tuesday_1`, `tuesday_2`, `tuesday_3` are not echoed/modified.